# indexedDB reusable function

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm making some prototype app who is using indexdDB and I can't figure out how to create reusable function.
For example I would like to create reusable function to retrieve LOV values. I know that it should be create somehow via events but I can't figure out how.
Could anyone please help?

Below is the code what I would like to bring in life

```js
function parent(){
    var lovValues = getLovValuesByType("STORE_TYPE");
    //lovType now is undefined
};

function getLovValuesByType(lovType){
    var returnedLovValues = new Array();
    var t = db.transaction(["LST_OF_VAL"], "readonly");
    var objectStore = t.objectStore("LST_OF_VAL");
    var INDEX = objectStore.index("TYPE");
    var REQUEST = INDEX.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only(lovType));
    REQUEST.onsuccess = function() {
        var CURSOR = REQUEST.result;
        if (CURSOR) {
            var value = this.result.value.VAL;
            returnedLovValues.push(value);
            this.result.continue();
        } else {
            return returnedLovValues; /// <------return data
        };
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `return` statement is returning from the callback function `REQUEST.onsuccess`. You don't return anything from `getLovValuesByType`, which is why `lovValues` is undefined.

The most straightforward solution is to use a callback function:

```
getLovValuesByType("STORE_TYPE", function (lovValues) {
    //lovType now is defined
);

function getLovValuesByType(lovTypem, cb){
    var returnedLovValues = new Array();
    var t = db.transaction(["LST_OF_VAL"], "readonly");
    var objectStore = t.objectStore("LST_OF_VAL");
    var INDEX = objectStore.index("TYPE");
    var REQUEST = INDEX.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only(lovType));
    REQUEST.onsuccess = function() {
        var CURSOR = REQUEST.result;
        if (CURSOR) {
            var value = this.result.value.VAL;
            returnedLovValues.push(value);
            this.result.continue();
        } else {
            cb(returnedLovValues);
        };
    };
};
```

More generally, you might want to do some reading about asynchronous JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, the callback was just what I was going to write as an answer. Instead of return, pass in a function that gets called. The key line above is cb(returned..).